# Java Doc -overview option (Using Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am using Eclipse to build a small Java project. I am wanting to include in my Java documentation the project overview, this is so that the index page contains information about the project title, its purpose etc.

I know that I can include an ovwerview.html page in my project and have done.

As per the Java Documentation, I have also read that I need to use an -overview option to activate the merging of my overview.html into the index page for the Java Doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDGDJAH

However, I do not know how to use this. On the third page of Eclipse's JavaDoc wizard is the option to include VM options and so I entred -overview "src/overview.html", but this had no effect. I tried just -overview "overview.html" but this had no effect either.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse JavaDoc wizard, you should have an "overview" field on the top of the third page.
[image: Overview field]

If so, you should be able to manually select it and then generate the javadoc.
If not, consider updating your JavaDoc plugin for Eclipse, if possible.

Comment: I so totally missed that one, thank you.